# why is webpack saying react is not defined here?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some code like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppRouter from './app/route';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


// Disable react dev tools in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    && window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__
    && Object.keys(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers).length
) window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers = {};

// Enable React hot reload in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    module.hot.accept('./app.js', () => {
        ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById('complianceApp'));
    });
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById('complianceApp'));
```

which works with webpack building it. I need to do similar stuff at a couple other places so I thought I would make a generic solution, taking most of that code out and putting it inside an SPA builder - like the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const spa_boilerplate = (component, path, elID) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    && window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__
    && Object.keys(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers).length
    ) { window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers = {};}

    // Enable React hot reload in development
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        module.hot.accept(path, () => {
            ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById(elID));
        });
    }

    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById(elId));
}

export default spa_boilerplate;
```

and then importing it into app.js like so

```
import AppRouter from './app/route';
import spa_boilerplate from './shared/spa_boilerplate';

spa_boilerplate(<AppRouter />,  '../../app.js', 'complianceApp');
```

When I run this I get the error message

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined

app.js line 4147 > eval:16:1
    <anonymous> webpack:///./src/app.js?:16
    js http://localhost:8001/app.js:4147
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8001/app.js:724
    fn http://localhost:8001/app.js:101
    <anonymous> webpack:///multi_(webpack)-dev-server/client?:3
    0 http://localhost:8001/app.js:4515
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8001/app.js:724
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8001/app.js:791
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8001/app.js:794
```

which if I look into what webpack built it has the following:

```
Object(_shared_spa_boilerplate__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(React.createElement(_app_route__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"], null), '../../app.js', 'complianceApp');
```

so I can see that there is no React defined in there  - how do I get it to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use jsx, in your case you use `<Approuter />` in app.js, it gets transpiled to `React.createSomethingOrOther`. Therefore you have to import React explicitly into any module that uses jsx. Just `import React from "react";` in your app.js.

Comment: yeah I just realized that myself and was answering the question, then when I did it I saw you answered so I give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import React to app.js?

```
import AppRouter from './app/route';
import spa_boilerplate from './shared/spa_boilerplate';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

spa_boilerplate(<AppRouter />,  '../../app.js', 'complianceApp');
```